# Calculating Standard Deviation of Annual Returns

Tags: python, metrics, finance

I have a pandas DataFrame with daily cumulative returns of two etf's!
ETF 1 has 795 entries (dates) and ETF 2 645 entries (dates)! I already calculated the CAGR(Average Annualized Return), Maximal Drawdown etc. but I'm confused about how to calculate the Annual Return Standard Deviation since I have more than 365 days! Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, can you please add a minimal runnable version of your data frame and current code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.std`.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(100)

print(np.std(A))
```

Comment: I used the following is this approach correct ??? yearly_Price = df['Cum. Returns'].resample('A').std()